# Is MULTI supposed to work on Redis clustered?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I'm using Redis on a clustered db (locally). I'm trying the `MULTI` command, but it seems that it is not working. Individual commands work and I can see how the shard moves.

Is there anything else I should be doing to make `MULTI` work? The documentation is unclear about whether or not it should work. https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

In the example below I just set individual keys (note how the port=cluster changes), then trying a multi command. The command executes before `EXEC` is called

```
127.0.0.1:30001> set a 1
-> Redirected to slot [15495] located at 127.0.0.1:30003
OK
127.0.0.1:30003> set b 2
-> Redirected to slot [3300] located at 127.0.0.1:30001
OK
127.0.0.1:30001> MULTI
OK
127.0.0.1:30001> HSET c f val
-> Redirected to slot [7365] located at 127.0.0.1:30002
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:30002> HSET c f2 val2
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:30002> EXEC
(error) ERR EXEC without MULTI
127.0.0.1:30002> HGET c f
"val"
127.0.0.1:30002>
```

Answer (score 5):

`MULTI` transactions, as well as any multi-key operations, are supported only within a single hashslot in a clustered Redis deployment.

Comment: thanks; do you know any Go client that handles clustering and transactions?

Comment: Any cluster client should be able to do transactions, but crossslot operations are not supported by Redis itself.

Comment: I ended up using github.com/go-redis/redis, works great